# jquery tools overlay rel alternative

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

Im using jquery tools overlay to display overlays when I click on a link.  I have 3 different overlays on the page.  The rel attribute of the link is set to the name/id of the overlay.

`<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="#custom">click to open overlay</a>`

The overlay is below :

`<div class="email_overlay" id="custom">`
`<div class="emailWrap"></div>`
`</div>`

The overlay is initialised below

`$("a[rel]").overlay();`

The problem is that I have several other links on the page that have rel="nofollow" on them.

This is causing errors as it is thinks the nofollow's are overlays.

What is the best work around for this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
$("a[rel^='#']").overlay();
```

It means - select all `a` tags with `rel` attribute starts with `#`

Comment: And me too.  Couldn't figure out for awhile why this was.